# <a> vs <button> vs <div> vs <input type='button">

Tags: html

I've seen so many posts along the lines of "I'd like to *one-specific-thing* for my *one-specific-situation* when it comes to buttons in HTML.

If I may, I'd like to get a professional take all in one post, here:

When making buttons in HTML, what situations lead to:

- `<a>` being the best answer?
- `<button>` being the best answer?
- `<div>` being the best answer?
- `<input type='button'>` being the best answer?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is far too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: That's part of the answer I'm seeking. I don't understand the varied "optimizations" where one gets argued to be better the others, so I have no idea how to understand why each keeps getting argued better than the others in situations.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There's a [**good article**](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-buttons) that summarizes the differences nicely

**In short:**

```
|                       |       General usage        | Complex designs | Can be disabled |
|-----------------------|----------------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
| <button>              | General button purpose.    | Yes             | Yes             |
|                       | Used in most cases         |                 |                 |
| --------------------- | -------------------------- | --------------- | --------------- |
| <input type="button"> | Usually used inside        | No              | Yes             |
|                       | forms                      |                 |                 |
| --------------------- | -------------------------- | --------------- | --------------- |
| <a>                   | Used to navigate to        | Yes             | No              |
|                       | pages and resources        |                 |                 |
| --------------------- | -------------------------- | --------------- | --------------- |
| <div>                 | Can be used for clickable  | Yes             | No              |
|                       | area which is not button   |                 |                 |
|                       | or link by definition      |                 |                 |
```

Answer (score 23):

Generally, I try to use the HTML tag in the most "semantic way" and useful way:

- `<a>` tag: a is for "anchor", I use it when the button is a link to a content on the page or external content;
- `div` tag: this is a simple container. I use it when I have to do simple buttons without any specific job but really custom style(simple animation, transition, open modal, etc). This is the jolly.
- `<button>` tag: according with W3, this is the standard tag to create buttons on the page, so use it when you need an action like onClick().
- `<input type="button">` tag: is equal to the button tag, but you need it for form submission, because browser that submit for with `<button>` can submit different values. I use it generally on form.

Comment: "Generally, I try to use the HTML tag in the most 'semantic way' and useful way.". This is spot on... Helped me clarify how I should think about it too...