# Get button name when clicked in Django

Tags: python, django

How can I get the name of a button when clicked ? Note that, the button is not in a form so I it does not work with `request.POST.get('button_name)'.
My button is more of the form:

```
<button onclick="location.href='{% url 'assigntask' %}'" type="button" name="Assign_Task">Assign Task</button>
```

I tried:

```
if request.POST.get('Assign_Task'):
    print "User Clicked Assign Task"
```

Comment: @Florent Sorry I dont speak French and my button is a standalone button and not in a form. I mentioned it in the question. The answer you provided is for buttons that are in a form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the name of the button as GET parameter:

```
<button onclick="location.href='{% url 'assigntask' %}?name=Assign_Task'" type="button">
  Assign Task
</button>
```

In your View get the name as follows:

```
name = request.GET.get('name')
```

As your button is used for navigation the `<a>` tag is a better option ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37148542/1189656)):

```
<a href="{% url 'assigntask' %}?name=Assign_Task">Assign Task</a>
```