# How to pass data between lit-element templates?

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, lit-html

I am trying to pass data from one component to another. My idea is to have a generic component with buttons that increase or decrease a value and add those specific values ​​to another template.

Here is my code with the buttons:

```js
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class ButtonsCounter extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            max: {type: Number},
            min: {type: Number},
            num: {type: Number},
            value: {type: Number},
        };
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.value = 0;
    }

    createRenderRoot() {
        return this;
    }

    increment(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.value < this.maxValue) this.value++;
    }

    decrement(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.value > this.minValue) this.value--;
    }

    render(){
        return html`
            <div class="searchCounter" max=${this.maxValue} min=${this.minValue}>
                <a href="#" @click="${this.decrement}"></a>
                <span num=${this.value}>${this.value}</span>
                <a href="#" @click="${this.increment}"></a>
            </div>
        `;
    }
}

customElements.define('buttons-counter', ButtonsCounter);
```

Here is the template where I want to add the data that will go to the previous template:

```js
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
import './buttons-counter'

class SelectOption extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.num = 0;
        this.max = 5;
        this.min = 0;
    }

    createRenderRoot() {
        return this;
    }

    render(){
        return html`
            <buttons-counter .max="${this.max}" .min="${this.min}" .num="${this.num}"></buttons-counter>
        `;
    };
}

customElements.define('select-option', SelectOption);
```

I've tried different ways but none works. Any idea?

Comment: Looks correct, what is exactly not working?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing up `value` with `num`, `maxValue` with `max`, and `minValue` with `min`.

You'll also likely want some text inside your `a` tags so that they're reasonably clickable.  Technically, they should also be `button` tags (styled to your liking), as `a` tags are considered for linking to parts of a page or to another page (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37148542/6090140 for more details).  You then will not need `e.preventDefault();` inside `decrement` and `increment`.

```
<button @click="${this.decrement}">-</button>
```